# How to POST a form with Django and not reload the page

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, django

I'm working on an app where the user will submit a value and I want to hide the div containing the form on submit and display a div containing the results. The goal is to have them submit the form and display a different hidden div. What am I doing wrong with either the Django code or Javascript?

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import VintageMac
from .forms import VintageMacForm

def home(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = VintageMacForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            form = VintageMacForm()
    else:
        form = VintageMacForm()
    return render(request, 'hmwypapp/index.html', {'form': form})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

models.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django import forms

class VintageMac(models.Model):
    price = models.IntegerField()

    def publish(self):
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.price)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import VintageMac

class VintageMacForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = VintageMac
        fields = ('price',)
```

HTML

```
<div id="submission1">
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title.</p>
                    <div class="bottom">
                      <div class="row">
                        <form action="/create_post/" class="w-100" method="POST" id="form1">
                          <div class="col-12">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                              {% for hidden_field in form.hidden_fields %}
                                {{ hidden_field }}
                              {% endfor %}
                            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                              <div class="form-control">
                                  {% render_field field min="0" class="form-control" id="amount1" placeholder="Type an amount." %}
                                  {% if field.help_text %}
                                <small class="form-text text-muted">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
                                {% endif %}
                              </div>
                            {% endfor %}
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-12">
                            <button onclick="myFunction1()" class="mt-1 text-center form-control btn submit-btn">Submit <span></span></button>
                          </div>
                        </form>
                      <div class="text-center credit mt-2 w-100">Submitted by @peterdenatale</div>
                      </div>
                    </div></div>
                    <div id="results1">
                      <p class="card-text">You said that you would pay <span class="value">$375.00</span> .</p>
                      <div class="bottom">
                          <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-12">
                                  <div class="progress">

                                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="65" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 65%;">
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: -20px;">
                                    <p class="col-4 raised-text"><strong>Min<br>$0.00</strong></p>
                                    <p class="col-4 average-text"><strong>Avg<br>$250.00</strong></p>
                                    <p class="col-4 goal-text"><strong>Max<br>$500.00</strong></p>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).on('submit','#form1',function(e){
e.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: '',
    data:{
        amount: $('#amount1').val(),
    },
    success:function(){
        $('#submission1').fadeOut(500);
        $('#results1').delay(500).fadeIn(500);
    }
});
```

I tried changing the JavaScript to a bunch of different things, but the only thing that it does it reload the page. I want to get rid of the reload and stay on the same page but still post the data and hide/show the divs.

Answer (score 0):

In line:

```
<button onclick="myFunction1()" class="mt-1 text-center form-control btn submit-btn">Submit <span></span></button>
```

Remove the `onclick` handler, add attribute `type` with value `submit`.

Updated line should look like:

```
<button type="submit" class="mt-1 text-center form-control btn submit-btn">Submit <span></span></button>
```

And update the `url` key in `$.ajax` options object to `/create_post/` (from `form` tag `action` attribute)

Comment: Okay. Just tried that, but it's still not working. Page just reloads still.

Answer (score 0):

1- I think you forgot to close the javascript tag that's why it doesn't work.
2- Change the submit button to be like this :

```
<input type="submit" class="mt-1 text-center form-control btn submit-btn" value="Submit"><span></span></div>
```

3- You forgot to add the csrf token in ajax as well , it should be like this :

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
```

Cheers :)